# can't install mssql-server in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, mssql

few days ago updated from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04 through updates
[img to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4NZL.png)

I previously had mssql-server installed, after the update finished I tried to run mssql-server (which did not happen due to an error), after that I decide to uninstall it and reinstall it.

When trying to install it I get the following error, not only when installing mssql-server but with anything else that I try to install through apt.
[error in consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbVt0.png)
I already tried apt-get autoremove, manually modify and delete files in etc/apt/
among other things that I saw reading in forums and the problem still persists.

Comment: Don't blindly copy and paste commands from the internet. You have added a repository for Ubuntu 18.04 (`bionic`) and now `apt` complains that this repo has no software for your current Ubuntu version. Remove everything from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that refers to MSSQL, or bionic, or Microsoft, and run `sudo apt update`. You should be able to install other software at that point.

Comment: I followed the official microsoft documentation for the installation of sql-server, which says that the same repository of Ubuntu 18.02 is used for Ubuntu 20.04, maybe this problem is fixed.

Comment: Please do not submit pictures of text, like your terminal.  Instead, copy-paste the content into the body of your question.  For commands and terminal output, use the formatting tools above the text box, or use Markdown language to render the text in a `monospace` font as it appears on your screen.  This allows us to accurately and easily transcribe the text in order to best help you.